# Is API fully supported in WSO2 ESB in the StratosLive cloud?

Tags: wso2, cloud, wso2-stratos, wso2-esb

I have a small WSO2 ESB 4.5.1 test app on-premise using the API functionality. I also have a developer account on WSO2 StratosLive and noticed that ESB there appears to be upgraded to ESB 4.5.x/Carbon 4.0. I can successfully deploy my API app on StratosLive without visible errors; however, I am seeing that my deployed API app "dissapears" after some period (i.e. I login to StratosLive later and the API app is no longer deployed). Other ESB proxies on StratosLive are fine.

Anyone know if this is a StratosLive management glitch or am I jumping the gun with using API on StratosLive?

Comment: Regarding the issue of your APis going missing, can you provide with your tenant domain in StratosLive and a name of an API which you created and later found missing?

Comment: My tenant domain is inmemoryspace.net. I deployed a simple API named HREmployeeAPI (that some time later dissapeared).

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 StratosLive has not been upgraded to WSO2 ESB 4.5.X yet. It is still powered by WSO2 ESB 4.0.2. But we have added the API capability sometime ago. We are also in the process of upgrading the StratosLive with WSO2 Carbon 4.0.x family of products. This will be available before end of 2012.